# How do I test if a URL returns http 404 error in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

How do I test if a URL returns http 404 error in ASP.NET MVC 3? I would like to write a small test to check if a view is being called when I write a specific URL.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this question/reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mock the httpContextBase of your controller with [mvcContrib-test](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcContrib.Mvc3.TestHelper-ci) helper and check what is the response status like that:

```
Response.StatusCode == 404;
```

Comment: Thanks gdoron, any other chance without installing any helper on dev and build machines?

Comment: @devdept, Welll you don't have to install anything, but mocking httpContext is a terrible headache.  BTW, it's just a package from nuget, why not install it and save time for coffee?